# Ordering columns in Microsoft SQL Server when they contain html tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I have several columns in a SQL Server database like this:

```
Column1                       Column2   
Item1                         <div id="html"><img.............>5424</div>
Item2                         <div id="html"><img.............>3424</div>
Item3                         <div id="html"><img.............>8424</div>
Item4                         <div id="html"><img.............>6424</div>
```

I would like to reorder them using ORDER BY based on the value inside of `>*</div>`, so that the output looks like this:

```
Column1                       Column2   
Item2                         <div id="html"><img.............>3424</div>
Item1                         <div id="html"><img.............>5424</div>
Item4                         <div id="html"><img.............>6424</div>
Item3                         <div id="html"><img.............>8424</div>
```

I am using the following code to extract the values from the database:

```
SELECT 
    Table1_1.F1 AS Column1, Table2_1.1PrisHTML AS Column2
FROM     
    Table2 AS Table2_1 
CROSS JOIN
    Table1 AS Table1_1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    Table1_1.L1, Table2_1.2PrisHTML
FROM     
    Table2 AS Table2_1 
CROSS JOIN
    Table1 AS Table1_1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    Table1_1.M1, Table2_1.3PrisHTML
FROM     
    Table2 AS Table2_1 
CROSS JOIN
    Table1 AS Table1_1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    Table1_1.T1, Table2_1.4PrisHTML
FROM
    Table2 AS Table2_1 
CROSS JOIN
    Table1 AS Table1_1
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

**Edit:**
I DO have the values in a separate column, called `Column3` which I can use for sorting. But I do not want to display this column. Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to break the value you want to sort on out into a separate column.  Do you have control over the table schema?

Comment: Hi. I do have the values in a separate column! So I can use them to sort. But don't want to display them.

Comment: As a rule of thumb you should never store HTML formatting in the database.

Comment: Just because it's there doesn't mean you have to display it. You don't even have to select it, just sort on it. But I agree that putting the html in the database is probably a bad idea. What happens when you realize that you shouldn't have more than one html element with the same id and have to change that? Or you want to change the class of the div? Is it one quick change in the html or a search and replace on your data?

Comment: Yes I agree, but in this case its only about 10 entires in a separate Table that won't change. I mean, the table won't have items added or deleted to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an `Order By` clause at the end of your SQL queries.  No need to add it to the select query.

I'd do it like this:

```
    SELECT Column1, Column2 
    FROM
    (
    SELECT Table1_1.F1 AS Column1, Table2_1.1PrisHTML AS Column2, Column3 
    FROM     Table2 AS Table2_1 CROSS JOIN
                      Table1 AS Table1_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Table1_1.L1 AS Column1, Table2_1.2PrisHTML AS Column2, Column3 
    FROM     Table2 AS Table2_1 CROSS JOIN
                      Table1 AS Table1_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Table1_1.M1 AS Column1, Table2_1.3PrisHTML AS Column2, Column3 
    FROM     Table2 AS Table2_1 CROSS JOIN
                      Table1 AS Table1_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Table1_1.T1 AS Column1, Table2_1.4PrisHTML AS Column2, Column3 
    FROM     Table2 AS Table2_1 CROSS JOIN
                      Table1 AS Table1_1
    )
    ORDER BY Column3
```

Comment: It was missing Column1 and Column2 aliases.  I added them.  Sorry about that.

Comment: doesn't work for me. the issue is that the name of the column3 are different for all the entries. For example for F1 its called F1Col3, for L1 it's called L1Col3, for M1 its M1Col3 for T1 its T1Col3

Comment: You're just going to have to alias out all of the columns so they're the same name, and then you can union and sort without issue.

Comment: ok works now, but not Column3 as sort, but just entering the different column names. Thanks